# What does `//` in javascript's src attribute do?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, unix, src

I'm using Facebook's javascript sdk and it has double forward slashes. What do they mean?

`<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`

I know a single `/` means root directory, but what is `//`? Is that telling the source to use `http://` and then the path?

Comment: See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a "protocol-relative" link. It uses http or https depending on what was used to load the current page.

Comment: HI @thilo Is it HTML 5 Specific or it will work with HTML 4 browsers too..

Comment: Can you use it in any other html tag? for instance, as the value for the `href` attribute in `<link/>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

It makes it protocol agnostic, if your page is served using https: it makes the request using https:

Answer (score 0):

Please find the details in these links this explains why we need double slash

http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

[Double slash at beginning of javascript include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350244/double-slash-at-beginning-of-javascript-include)