# // when including third party JavaScript libs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm seeing these kind of script includes on third party sites all the time these days, for example, for the Google Maps API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
```

What does this prefix of '//' mean ? That it uses whatever protocol the user is running (http, https)?

Comment: Look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785442/browser-support-for-urls-beginning-with-double-slash, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350244/double-slash-at-beginning-of-javascript-include, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It means use the same protocol as was used to load the page - either http or https

This is done so that you don't get a warning about loading "insecure" content when viewing over SSL